# How do I recompile X.org from git?

Tags: xorg, compiling, git

I am having some problems with wheelmouse and mouse movement at the same time on ubuntu 12.04 and I found that the problem has been solved here:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/?id=2d4fda4b09e67e47d3e6fc4743fc6e81bfe40f28

How do I apply these changes to my own system as this would resolve my problem I'm having perfectly!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fetch the Ubuntu source to your computer, apply the patch, rebuild Xorg, install, and test the result. Rebuilding the package is a rather advanced topic, I don't know how experienced you are.

Another approach would be to wait a couple of months if you can. The quantal-proposed branch appears to me to have that patch. I'm referring to [this code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/quantal/xorg-server/quantal-proposed/view/head:/hw/xfree86/common/xf86Xinput.c#L1063) on Launchpad. This is currently being tested and if testing is OK will probably be incorporated into the Quantal 12.10 release in October.

Comment: I have overcome the issue by adding the code manually and recompiling. Wasn't actually that easy or reliable, so will wait and see what they come up with, thanks.